# open .VCE file programmatically in android

Tags: android

I searched a lot on net to find a way to programmatically access .VCE file in android, but didn't find anything.

**So is it possible to open .VCE file in android programmatically?**

If yes then how can I open it. Please give any reference link if anybody knows.